# how to check which web hosting a website using?

Tags: webserver, ip, web-hosting, ping

I am trying to find out which web hositng a vidoe streaming site name "ABC" using.

When I trying to ping "ABC", it gives me back a IP, I looked up on Internet..

It's a company called http://www.cloudflare.com/, I think this site offer something service to prevent IP attacking...

And my clue stopped here, and clicked play on the video player, it doesnt give me any clue which web hosting compnany it using... or is the video located on amazon s3?

Any way to check that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what server type they are running you can try

http://netcraft.com/ -> what this site running?

but it won't give you the right answer if site using something like a caching service. See microsoft.com

If you want to know what hosting company they are using you can try running a reverse lookup on the IP to find out who owns it.

http://www.ipchecking.com

Chances are that the actual hosting company rents the IP from the owner so this information would not be useful. You could try asking the IP owner but unless you have a subpoena you may not get far.

You might get lucky by checking the name servers registered for the domain. You will get 3 different answers with that. They belong to a dns hosting service and not the web host. They belong to the webhost. They were named for the domain name itself. So only useful if they use the webhost dns and then the webhost might use a different name for their dns service.

Comment: thanks , but i not even can grap their ip...

Comment: dig www.example.com or nslookup www.example.com

Comment: You have to be able to get the IP because their site can't work without it.

Comment: yes. but the ip address keep changing , it shows up asia, eouroupe , US, in the ten minutes, thats why its the problem :(

Comment: I gave you 2 checks that don't use IP addresses.

Comment: the dig and nslookup gives me the ip address, but they are dynamic changing every few minutes

Comment: The other two searches I gave you use the domain name.